# Smarter customer service e-mail, how to?

Tags: linux, email, service

Right now I just have an e-mail on my domain that I use for customer service and I answer all of the e-mails myself.  However, my business has grown enough that I'm losing a lot of time answering all of these e-mails that others could be answering.  I want to be able to give someone else an e-mail address to use for customer service e-mails, but allow them to pass off e-mails that he can't deal with.  It wouldn't work for them to just forward the e-mail to me because it would then be from them and would make it inconvenient when trying to reply to the customer.  I'm on a server with WHM/Cpanel, what would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use a separate helpdesk application for this, then the easiest and most common way to do this is to use a separate IMAP mailbox for the 'support' email address, that both you and your staff have access to.

Then you simply create a folder called "Handover" where your employee puts all the emails he wants to hand over to you.

The added benefit here is that all email communication with customers will be handled via this one account, so there's no risk for confusion or late replies like there is if customers reply to a personal email account.

Comment: This is how we handled mail for a help desk of 5+ employees.  One account that all users pulled mail from and all could respond to.